# MPI Reduce on sum of partial sums not working

Tags: mpi

I am trying to get the sum of partial sums by sending portions of an array to n processes (in this case let n = 2). After I send these portions, the other processes receive and calculate their partial sums. Here's the part I'm having trouble with: the program works correctly when I send the sums to the the master core (0) and receive at core 0. But with MPI_REDUCE, it only calculates a portion of the array. Here's the program:

```
// size of array
#define n 10

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

// Temporary array for other process
int a2[1000];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int pid, np, elements_per_process, n_elements_recieved;

    int partial_sum = 0; //local sums
    int sum = 0;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    // master process
    if (pid == 0) {
       int index, i;
       elements_per_process = n / np;

       // check if more than 1 processes are run
      if (np > 1) {
        // distributes the portion of array
        for (i = 1; i < np - 1; i++) {
        index = i * elements_per_process;
                MPI_Send(&elements_per_process,1, MPI_INT, i, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&a[index],elements_per_process, MPI_INT, i, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        // last process adds remaining elements
        index = i * elements_per_process;
        int elements_left = n - index;

        MPI_Send(&elements_left,1, MPI_INT,i, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&a[index], elements_left,MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }

       // master process add its own sub array
       for (i = 0; i < elements_per_process; i++)
       sum += a[i]; //this is the only line bein calcuated into sum
                        // mpi_reduce is not catching the other local sums

       printf("Sum of array is : %d\n", sum);
           // should print 55, but prints 15 (when using 2 processes)
           // meaning its only adding the first half of the numbers
    }
    // other processes
    else {
      MPI_Recv(&n_elements_recieved, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      // stores the received array segment
      // in local array a2
      MPI_Recv(&a2, n_elements_recieved,MPI_INT, 0, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      // calculates its partial sum
     for (int i = 0; i < n_elements_recieved; i++)
       partial_sum += a2[i];

    }

    MPI_Reduce(&partial_sum,&sum, n, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if i should be using MPI_SCATTER but if I do need to use it, I'm not sure how to use it for an odd number of elements since the input array can change.

Comment: please copy/paste your full code, share your `mpirun` command line and add a test to validate the output.
you can have each rank print its `partial_sum` to get a hint at the root cause. if `n%np != 0`, you would typically use `MPI_Scatterv()` to distribute the data. Note each rank can figure out `n_elements_received` based on its rank and `n` only, so you do not need to send/recv this information.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you for your response, it really helped me solve my issue. I just have question: Since MPI_Scatterv() doesn't require me to send `n_elements_recieved`, would that mean that, for example `MPI_Bcast( array, b, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` wouldn't require me to send `b`(the size of the array)? Would each process by default receive `b`?

Comment: My point is `n_elements_received` can be computed locally by each rank, and this should be preferred since it is way faster than send/recv. In this code, the size of the array (`n`) is macro defined and hence known on all the ranks, so there is no need to communicate it.